# How to get data from other states angular ui router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to hide, show menu base on the data role in each state

```
.state('index.admin1', {
    url: "/admin1",
    templateUrl: "views/admin1.html",
    data: {
        pageTitle: 'Admin view',
        roles: ['admin']
    },
})
```

But i don't know how to get all state's data and check roles's value and use ng-if to show hide each menu that has its roles. Is there a solution to check all states data?

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want to access data send from one state in another state?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are using `ui-router`  `0.2.11` and later you can do something like this.

```
   $stateProvider
   .state('index.admin1', {
        url: "/admin1",,
        templateUrl: "views/admin1.html",
        params: {pageTitle:null, roles:null},
    })
```

when you navigate to a different state you can pass data you want like this

```
$state.go('index.admin1', { pageTitle: 'title', roles: ['admin'] })
```

Once you go to `index.admin1` state you can access data like this

```
app.controller('overviewController', function($scope, $stateParams) {
    $scope.pageTitle= $stateParams.pageTitle;
    $scope.roles= $stateParams.roles;
});
```

Take a look [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1949).